# How to return all combinations of two teams in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm working on a Tournament Manager and I'm starting to work on the match system. My question is how can I return all combinations of two teams and then I'll be able to create matches with those combinations ? 
Let me explain a bit. One team belongs to only one pool. In the "Team" model, 
I have a foreign key field that references the pool to which the team belongs. In my algorith, I'd like to create matches played by two teams that belongs to the same pool. For exemple I have team A, B, C, D, I want to create match A vs B, match A vs C, match A vs D, and so on

I looked a bit here : https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html, and I found "combinations" function but nothing more.

**`models.py`**

```
class Match(models.Model):
    scoreTeam1  = models.IntegerField()
    scoreTeam2  = models.IntegerField()
    phase       = models.ForeignKey(Phase, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teams       = models.ManyToManyField(Team, default=None, blank=True)

class Pool(models.Model):
    name    = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    nbTeam  = models.IntegerField(validators=[
                                    MaxValueValidator(4),
                                    MinValueValidator(3)
                                ])
    phase   = models.ForeignKey(Phase, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field   = models.ForeignKey(Field, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Team(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    totalpoints = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    position    = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    category    = models.ForeignKey(Category, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pool        = models.ForeignKey(Pool, default=None, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

**`views.py`**

```
def matches_phase_view(request, id, id_phase, *args, **kwargs):
    tournaments = Tournament.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    tournament = Tournament.objects.get(pk=id)
    phase = Phase.objects.get(pk=id_phase)
    pools = Pool.objects.filter(phase=phase)
    teams = Team.objects.filter(pool__in=pools)

    matches_count = 0
    for pool in pools:
        matches_count = matches_count + pool.nbTeam * (pool.nbTeam - 1) // 2
    for pool in pools:
        teams_combinations = combinations(Team.objects.filter(pool=pool), 2)
        list_teams_combinations = list(teams_combinations)
        for combination in list_teams_combinations:
            match = Match.objects.create(phase=phase)
            match.teams.add(combination[0])
            match.teams.add(combination[1])
            match.save()

    matches = Match.objects.filter(phase=phase)
    context = {
        'tournaments': tournaments,
        'tournament': tournament,
        'pools': pools,
        'teams': teams,
        'matches_count': matches_count,
        'matches': matches,
    }
    return render(request, 'tournament_manage_phase_matches.html', context)
```

I tried this:

```
for pool in pools:
        a = combinations(Team.objects.filter(pool=pool), 2)
```

But I've got this error :

> name 'combinations' is not defined

If someone has a better idea, I'd like to hear it.

I'm using Python 3.7, Django 2.2.

Edit :

**`template`**

```
{% extends 'base_tournament.html' %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}
  Tournament
{% endblock %}

{% block navbar_manage %}
    {% include 'navbar_manage.html' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Matches of ...</h1>

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    {% for pool in pools %}
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="{{ pool.name }}-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#{{ pool.name }}" role="tab" aria-controls="{{ pool.name }}" aria-selected="true">{{ pool.name }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
        {% for pool in pools %}
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="{{ pool.name }}" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="{{ pool.name }}-tab">
                {% for match in matches %}
                    <p>Wait for a moment</p>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from itertools import combinations`

Comment: Ok and when I'm doing ```a = combinations(Team.objects.filter(pool=pool), 2)```, how can I take a look to the content of "a" ? It returns me a list ?

Comment: `for combination in a:
    print(combination)
`
 or 
`print(list(a))`

Comment: Ok I already tried it and it worked ! Now I'll be able to create my matches and to edit scores, you were very helpful !

Comment: Sorry but a question came to me now. How can I display matches depending on a specific pool ? I'm going to edit my post and add my modifications and my template. I can't find how to filter matches depending on the pool.